# Helper method for calling generic methods with reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Does anyone have a better way to do the following:

```
typeof(Service).GetMethod("UpdateData")
    .MakeGenericMethod(dataType)
    .Invoke(_myService, new object[]{ editData, metaData });
```

I'd love to do something like:

```
_myService.UpdateData<dataType>(editData, metaData);
```

But the <> accessor for generics will not take Type objects. I'm looking for a helper, utility, accessor, or something to make those generic method calls with reflection less cumbersome or at least centralized.

More Specific Example

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
  async Task<User> UpdateUser<T>(User user, JsonPatchDocument<T> patch){ //do code }
}

Type dtoType = MagicService.getDynamicDtoType();
Type patchType = typeof(JsonPatchDocument<>).MakeGenericType(dtoType);
dynamic patchDoc = _mapper.Map(patch, typeof(JsonPatchDocument<User>), patchType);
User updateUser = await (Task<User>)typeof(UserService).GetMethod("UpdateUser").MakeGenericMethod(dtoType).Invoke(_userService, new object[]{user, patchDoc})
```

This actually ends up with two issues. One, the `dynamic patchDoc` isn't the right type to be used in `UpdateUser`, which I have a separate question in Stackoverflow about (but you can use duck typing here), and the messy calling of that generic method call with reflection. I'm trying to solve both, but for this question I want to clean up the call. If you have ideas on the other piece, which is really a separate issue:
[Declaring a type in C# with a Type instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979601/declaring-a-type-in-c-sharp-with-a-type-instance?noredirect=1#comment100495202_56979601)

Comment: What's the reason for the use of generics, here?

Comment: @dez I have a specific use case for them. I'm not having any problem dealing with the generics and making the functional. I just don't like the messy syntax and am looking for a way to make it cleaner.

Comment: It seems like in order to write this code you would have to already know that the method exists. Reflection is for discovering members at runtime. If you already know that there's an `UpdateData` method to discover, why use reflection to call it? I'm not saying there's not a reason, just that it's not apparent from the question.

Comment: @ScottHannen yeah I wrote the `UpdateData` method. The reason I have to use reflections here is because the `dataType` is a `Type` instance that is dynamically chosen. It's not always the same, and C# doesn't seem to have support for generics from a `Type` instance without using reflection. So now I'm trying to clean it up some so it's not such a chunky call by using a helper of some sort.

Comment: Are you looking for this:  `public static class UpdateServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void UpdateData(this UpdateService updateService, 
            Type dataType, 
            Something editData, 
            Something metaData)
        {
            typeof(UpdateService).GetMethod("UpdateData")
                .MakeGenericMethod(dataType)
                .Invoke(updateService, new object[] { editData, metaData });
        }
    }`

Comment: @ScottHannen That works for this specific instance, but I was hoping there was some better way to get some more generic syntax that worked similar to the <> accessors. Using the above, I'd need to write a new helper method for every call that involved a call to a method using a dynamic Type.

Comment: I understand the problem somewhat now. Sometimes we have to write non-generic code that deals with `Type`, and connecting that back to generic code can be messy. Sometimes if I have to go non-generic part of the way I go non-generic all the way. How pervasive is the problem? Can you modify the target class? You could move the body of the methods into non-generic overloads with a `Type` argument, and then the generic overloads call the non-generic overloads using `typeof(T)`.

Comment: A generic type parameter is a compile-time parameter. That is the whole point. It is not there to make your code look nicer. If the type is not known until run-time, you should not (and cannot) pass it as a compile-time.

Comment: @JohnWu Thats not entirely true though because you can call a generic with reflection using a Type instance which is determined at runtime, so it is possible. The compiler just doesn't have a proper way of dealing with that that I can find without some messy trash dot chaining and no proper way to pass the response as it now technically doesn't have a type.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn’t clear. You are passing run time parameters (enclosed in parentheses) and not generic type parameters (enclosed in angle brackets) in order to invoke a generic method via Reflection. The reason it isn’t “proper” is because it is a workaround.

Comment: How does `T` relate to `User`? Is `User` a base class and `T` is the actual type of `user` that you expect? I'm guessing that what you're trying to do here is have some type specific logic which applies the JSON patch in the right way to each derived  `User` type, is that correct? Have you considered using a strategy pattern instead? Since you clearly have closed generic methods for a number of types you could also have a method which takes `dtoType` and returns one of those functions e.g. as a `Func<User, JsonPatchDocument, Task<User>>`. You could then just call that function.

Comment: @dez T is a dto. From what I've seen the dtos don't tend to have an inheritance structure to them, as they are standalone data containers that the mapper maps between. If I made User a base class, the other dtos would then have ALL of the properties of a User, should the dtos inherit from it, and I wouldn't be able to limit the input. Essentially, User is the EF Entity Model with all properties. Something like a UserAdminInput has just the fields that admins can edit, sanitizing the params.So a UserAdminInput would be the dynamically found dtoType. Hope that clears up the use case.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're encoding field access permissions as different types. As you're using JSON Patch one option might be to instead encode the field access permissions as a list of paths the user is allowed to modify and then you pick the appropriate list of paths and strip any Operation instances from the JsonPatchDocument that don't match one of those paths.

Comment: @dez Well, I'm actually using this for all controller methods, not just patch. For creating a user, it pulls the role and then would use, say for an admin, the UserAdminInput DTO to sanitize out unwanted parameters. I did get it working, but I ended up mapping to the dynamic with the returned DTO type, then mapping back to the model type and passing that to the service. Should sanitize out everything as I need, I think. Haven't had a chance to test yet, but open to better ideas.

Comment: You could still use a patch for a create. Just implement it as a patch of an empty object. Storing the access rules as data rather than a type also has the advantage that, in the future, you can change the rules without needing to recompile your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer does not use reflection, but *may* make your code easier to work with in *some* circumstances.

We could have a class like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    public void UpdateData<T>(Something data, Something otherData)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Later we find that we have to call it using a `Type` variable instead of a generic argument, which could mean using reflection. Sometimes it's easier to add a non-generic overload to the original class, and call it from the generic method:

```
public class MyService
{
    public void UpdateData(Type dataType, Something data, Something otherData)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    public void UpdateData<T>(Something data, Something otherData)
    {
        UpdateData(typeof(T), data, otherData);
    }
}
```

We lose the ability to easily impose constraints on the `Type` argument like we could with the generic method. We can add validation if we need it.

That gets you as close as possible to the code you're trying to write:

```
_myService.UpdateData(dataType, editData, metaData);
```

That's assuming that you find yourself still needing the generic methods at all. If you add non-generic overloads and discover that you're not calling the generic ones anymore, you can just delete them.

A significant benefit of this over reflection is that you can identify where your code is called. A method that's only called using reflection will appear unused.

Comment: This gets me back to the same spot trying to call UpdateData<T> because T is dynamic. I have code that fetches a Type instance based on a few factors and returns that, which I'm then using to call a generic function. I have to call the function as a generic because a parameter requires a generic passed in as well, and I can't use a Type instance for that. I'll update with a more specific example. See OP.

Comment: Now that you've added more code to the OP, I feel your pain. Once we have a `Type` instead of a generic argument, bridging that back to use generic code is messy. The reflection could be inevitable. While my answer might help in some cases, in your case I don't see any way around writing an extension that uses reflection.

Comment: I've ended up needing to pass around things as dynamic and use duck typing too, since casting is a compile time thing. :/ My main issue here is that I'm using dynamically chosen DTOs based on user role which fall through to a base DTO if no class exists for that user role. I'm using it for sanitizing params (like an admin can edit all params on a user, but a user should only be able to edit their name). Rails and Elixir (not compiled of course) have sanitization of the json before it even gets parsed and mapped, but I see nothing like that for .NET Core, so I'm building my own I guess.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer to this particular question as it's likely the more typical route. In my case, I simply mapped to the DTO dynamically chosen to sanitize, then mapped back to the model EF entity and passed it to the service. This will work for everything accept for a PUT, where you'll need to pass the dynamic DTO, which I haven't found a better way than the OP to do or to just let your service accept a dynamic and duck type it.